Tikz externalization with luacode
I'm using luacode environments to assemble plot code for pgfplots. For many plots that works perfectly fine even with tikzexternalize. However, I have one plot where it does not work and the error message is cryptic. I reduced it to:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
    %\tikzexternaldisable % doesn't compile with externalization, don't know why
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \begin{luacode*}
                local t = {}
                table.insert(t, "(0, 0)")
                table.insert(t, "(1, 1)")
                tex.print("\\addplot coordinates {")
                tex.print(table.concat(t))
                tex.print("};")
            \end{luacode*}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

So I used to get an error message like this:
File ended while scanning use of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpicture

I thought it might be related to a percent sign in the lua code (which I used for string.format), but I removed them. Now the strings are assembled a bit more manually. The problem persists, however, I don't get an error message any more. It just fails and it also does not create a main-figure0.log file, only the .md5 file. So what is going on?

I can't reproduce the issue, when I run this code as-is then I get the -figure0.log and -figure0.pdf and the md5.

I get the same when compiled with lualatex --shell-escape .... can you try in a clean directory and new document?

Yes, you are right, my mistake. I moved the code from my real document somewhere else and forgot shell-escape...
Well, at least I still figured out the error, apparently %s in messes up the finding of the \end{tikzpicture} (or something similar to that).

I figured out the problem, but it was not reproducible in the code I showed. Here is the original (erroneous) code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
    \tikzexternaldisable % doesn't compile with externalization, don't know why
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \begin{luacode*}
                local t = {}                
                table.insert(t, string.format("(%f, %f)", 0, 0))
                table.insert(t, string.format("(%f, %f)", 1, 1))
                tex.print(string.format("\\addplot coordinates {%s};", table.concat(t)))
            \end{luacode*}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but I guess it has to do with the {%s} in the format string. Citing the the tikz manual:

It can’t expand macros during this step, so the only requirement is
that every picture’s end is directly reachable from its beginning,
without further macro expansion. Furthermore, the library assumes that
all LATEX pictures are ended with \end{tikzpicture}. The library
always searches for the next picture’s end, \end{tikzpicture}.

It is probably related to the } following the percent sign. So here as a reference: If you encounter this problem, try to re-arrange code so that this sequence does not occur. See also the code in my question for comparison.
